# Как вывести блок повторителя (ACF) странице магазина?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, acf

В woocommerce.php, в корне темы прописал цикл для вывода блока повторителя:

```
    <?php 
  while ( have_posts() ) :
    the_post();

    //ACF Flexible Builder
    if (have_rows('блоки')):
        while (have_rows('блоки')):
            the_row();
              ...
            if (get_row_layout() == 'обложка') : get_template_part('blocks/slider_49_71702'); endif; // обложка
              ...
        endwhile;
    endif;
    //ACF Flexible Builder

  endwhile; // End of the loop. 
?>
```

но он ничего не выводит. Если просто подключить шаблон в woocommerce.php, то выводится все кроме полей из блока. Пробовал указывать id страницы вместе с названием поля, но это не помогло. У меня небольшой опыт работы с woocommerce, но как-то я работал с ним и помню что там был шаблон shop.php. В теме с которой я работаю сейчас его нет. Я добавил его и перенес в него код из woocommerce.php, но это так же не помогло. На других страницах и в рубриках все работает как надо. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: `$shop_page_id = wc_get_page_id('shop');` и передайте `$shop_page_id` в качестве второго параметра в `have_rows()`

Comment: стало лучше только вот теперь обложек слишком много.  почему то блок выводится 16 раз. пытаюсь понять почему

Comment: убрал первый while и все заработало!